# Java - LP solvers dynamic link error

Tags: java, windows, dll, dynamic-linking, linear-programming

I am having problems with linear programming solvers on a project I am working on. Firstly I tried using Ajanta, but this won't solve the class of problems I needed to solve. So I tried GLPK and lp_solve, but It seems I can't make Windows understand where the dynamic libraries are.

I put the stub (the .dll that links the code with java) and the actual code of the libraries (it seems usual that they come separated) on C:\Windows\System32 and I checked the following:
- The path variable is correctly set for searching on this directory.
- I correctly linked the java library with my program.
- I checked the dependencies with Dependency Walker and this program finds everything. (http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

I am working on Windows 7 with JRE/JDK 6 update 26. I am coding on Eclipse, also.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a compile time or run time error?  That might help debugging

Comment: Runtime. It seems caused by Windows not finding the algorithms library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently coding with Apache Commons. The package Math includes a Simplex solver class, which I reccomend. I leave this here for people who may find it useful.